# Worklight 6. 2 App on Blackberry Z10 cannot connect to WL server error CERT_EXPIRY

Tags: blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a Worklight 6.2 application that works on Android, iPhone. It's working also on Blackberry as long as I try to connect to local WL development network.
The problem is that we have our live WL server on a https connection.

On console I have the following error:

```
[myHttpsServer/apps/services/api/SalesApp/blackberry10/init] Host is not responsive. worklight.js:5053
__log worklight.js:5053
(anonymous function) worklight.js:5437
onUnresponsiveHost worklight.js:3595
(anonymous function) worklight.js:950
respondToReadyState worklight.js:1173
onStateChange worklight.js:1106
(anonymous function) worklight.js:950
POST myHttpsServer/apps/services/api/SalesApp/blackberry10/init CERT_EXPIRY [native code]:1
send [native code]:1
request worklight.js:1091
initialize worklight.js:1054
klass worklight.js:518
sendRequest worklight.js:3402
initialize worklight.js:3270
klass worklight.js:518
sendInitRequest worklight.js:8104
connect worklight.js:8110
connectionFailure startupController.js:63
(anonymous function)
```

I've imported the SSL certificate on the Blackberry Z10 device, Settings->Security->Certificates. I still get the same error.
Blackberry port was done using Webworks 1.0.

If I am running it on Blackberry device the Android application, it's working also.

If any ideea, please help.

Comment: The error says the certificate has expired; make sure it is not so.

Comment: Hello Idan, Thank you for your answer. I've checked the Certificate and it is not expired. Our Worklight Server SSL certificate is Alpha SSL CA SHA256 - G2, and expires on 20 Feb 2024. And GlobalSign Root CA expires on Jan 28, 2028.

Comment: I've got the answer here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Worklight-SSL-connection-CERT-EXPIRY-on-Z10-OS-10-2-3062/m-p/3054143#M44715

Answer (score 1):

I've got the Answare from Blackberry: [Link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Worklight-SSL-connection-CERT-EXPIRY-on-Z10-OS-10-2-3062/m-p/3054143#M44715)

> This is a known issue and will be fixed in the upcoming BlackBerry
>   10.3.1 OS update.